# Only Text is loading from my website on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

www.ultrapestsolution.com

This is a website I have developed as a beginner, but with some hard luck it's not loading properly on Firefox. It is loading properly on Chrome and IE but not on Firefox.

Please Help me !!!

Comment: Would be good to add some code or something because when you have your solution and you change your website, this question gets irrelevant.

Comment: where did you put `jquery-1.11.2.min.js` file ?i see 404 error for lot of files images and js scripts

Comment: Open the console and see the errors: `16:25:08.060 ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
 jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js:1:1
16:25:08.063 ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
 slick.min.js:1:129
16:25:08.063 ReferenceError: $ is not defined
 www.ultrapestsolution.com:419:5
16:25:08.063 ReferenceError: $ is not defined` You have not defined jquery. This site (stackoverflow) is not for this kind of problems. Solve by yourself.

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting [the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/hw3dIOE.png  404

Answer (score 1):

Ok! Your path declarations are wrong:

instead of:

```
<link media="screen" type="text/css" href="layerslider\css\layerslider.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

USE:

```
<link media="screen" type="text/css" href="layerslider/css/layerslider.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Note the backslah vs fwd slash difference.

This is the standard. Needless to say, fix it for ALL your static files, script (.js) and styles (.css) and images.

The static files are not loading therefore the jQuery, CSS etc are not executing.

Comment: oops!!! What a Silly mistake I have made. BTW Thanks a lot for this catch. Resolved it so easily.